# Java Read File Class not creating arraylist

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to populate an ArrayList with data stored in a text file, the data is 5 different values separated by white space, and a mix of boolean, strings and integers. Also, I'm using BlueJ, not sure if that changes anything though.

When the data is read from the file, objects of type Room should be created based on that data

I am new to Java, I've just started learning it within the last few weeks, my read data class is as follows:

Room Data Class:

```
public class RoomData
{
   //Default Values of a Room
   private int roomNumber = 0;
   private int bookingNights = 0;
   private boolean hasEnSuite = false;
   private boolean isBooked = false;
   private String bookingName = "<None>";

   public void setRoomNumber(int roomNumber) 
   {
       this.roomNumber = roomNumber;
   }

   public void setBookingNights(int bookingNights)
   {
       this.bookingNights = bookingNights;
    }

   public void setHasEnSuite()
   {
       this.hasEnSuite = hasEnSuite;
   }

   public void setIsBooked()
   {
       this.isBooked = isBooked;
   }

   public void setBookingName()
   {
       this.bookingName = bookingName;
   }
   }
```

ReadDataClass:

```
public class ReadHotelData
{
    private String filePath;

    public ReadHotelData()
    {
        filePath = "hotelData.txt";
    }

    private List<RoomData> list = new ArrayList <>();

    public boolean hasNext() throws FileNotFoundException 
    {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("hotelData.txt"));

        while (s.hasNext())
        {
           String nextLine = s.nextLine(); //reads text file line by line
           RoomData roomData = new RoomData();

           String[] values = nextLine.split(" "); // splits the text file by white space

           roomData.setRoomNumber(Integer.parseInt(values[0]));
           roomData.setBookingNights(Integer.parseInt(values[1]));

           roomData.setHasEnSuite(Boolean.parseBoolean(values[2]));
           roomData.setIsBooked(Boolean.parseBoolean(values[3]));

           roomData.setBookingName(String.parseString(values[4]));

           list.add(roomData);
        }// end loop
        s.close();
        return true;
    }

    public List <RoomData> getRoomDataList() 
    {
        return list;
    }
}
```

Like I said I'm new so if I'm missed anything I'd really appreciate any help!

Example of data stored in text file:

```
0 false David 0 false
0 true John 0 false
0 false Jim 0 true
```

Comment: So what are you having problems with?

Comment: I want an arraylist to be created when the code is ran, the arraylist is stored in another class called 'Hotel' [link](http://imgur.com/93poXZA) is how my project currently sits

Comment: Do you want to read each row into an element of the list? The code you have already reads all the token into the arraylist, You need to have a getter method which returns it so you can use it anywhere you want.

Comment: @A4L yes, the hotel arraylist contains rooms, and each of those rooms has 5 variables that are stored in the text file and when the program is booted up, it should read from this text file

Comment: @A4L do you mean like this? [link](http://imgur.com/1GPE90l) I don't how what you mean by split and parse so i'll have to look that up. (Sorry I didnt know how to post code in here)

Comment: @Aaranihlus the `RoomData` part is OK, but the `nextLine` and adding parts to the list aren't, please check my edit. PS: to add code to your question just click edit and paste it in the position you want, select it and press `Ctrl+k` to format it.

Comment: @A4L I've updated my question, is that where the parse and value code should go?

Comment: @Aaranihlus not exactly, the `list.add(roomData);` needs to be inside the loop (see comment in my example // end of while). `RoomData roomData = new RoomData();` needs to happen before parsing, so that you can do - for example for `roomNumber` - : `roomData.setRoomNumber(Integer.parseInt(values[0]);)` and so on.

Comment: @A4L OP updated again, more like that? Sorry to be a pain

Comment: @Aaranihlus looks better but still doesn't compile, the semicolon should be at the end of statement `roomData.setRoomNumber(Integer.parseInt(values[0]));` also no need for `String s` in `parseBoolean`, and you need to respect the format you actually have in your file, the sample data you posted shows `int boolean String int boolean`, but you parse in this order `int boolean boolean int String`, this will give exceptions at runtime. Finally please enable automatic compilation in your IDE so that you can see compile errors as soon as sou type them, which you have to correct before going further.

Comment: @A4L I've added the room data class to the OP, I think I have them set in the same order in both classes, but I do get a runtime error saying that the actual and formal arguments list differs in length, have I missed something? Or is it a problem with another class?

Comment: @Aaranihlus Not all your setter methods are declared to take a parameter, for example `public void setHasEnSuite()` should be `public void setHasEnSuite(boolean hasEnSuite)`

Comment: @A4L Wow, you must have eagles eyes lol. Compiles properly until the  booking name String, cannot find symbol? should it be roomData.setBookingName(values[4]);? <compiles fine

Comment: @Aaranihlus, there is no method `String.parseString`, all elements in `values` are of type `String`, so yes `roomData.setBookingName(values[4]);` is correct, no need to parse/convert.

Comment: IT READS! Thank you so much @A4L! You're an absolute life saver, how do I give you the proper rep? and thanks for being so patient and helpful! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create a class `RoomData` to hold the data for each room and give each variable a meaningful name along with the appropriate type.

Change your arraylist to hold that type instead of `String`

```
private List<RoomData> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

Read each line using [s.nextLine()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextLine--)

```
while(s.hasNext())
{
    String nextLine = s.nextLine();
    RoomData roomData = new RoomData();
```

Create an instance of that class, [split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) and parse each value into the corresponding variable in the instance of `RoomData` you have created.

```
  String[] values = nextLine.split(" ") // split by space
  // lets say you have "0 false David 0 false"
  // values[0] would be "0"
  // values[1] would be "false"
  // values[2] would be "David"
  // values[3] would be "0"
  // values[4] would be "false"
```

All the values in `values` would be of type `String` you will need to convert those from String to the type you have defined in `RoomData`, for int you can use [Integer.parseInt(String s)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt-java.lang.String-), for boolean there is a similar method (Boolean.parseBoolean(String s))[http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html#parseBoolean-java.lang.String-], string values can be set directly.

Add that instance to the arraylist.

```
    list.add(roomData);

} // end of while
```

Add a getter method to return that list for use in other classes.

```
public List<RoomData> getRoomDataList() {
    return list;
}
```

Comment: Or make the RoomData constructor parse a line.

Comment: @Robert how would I do that?

Comment: @Aaranihlus Just make a constructor that takes a String, e.g., `public RoomData(String line)`, then have parsing code like A4L showed above, using split and assigning to member variables as needed.